# A better way to insert rows from one table into another table, when none of the rows already exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a better way to insert rows from one table into another table, when none of the rows already exist?

```
-- Insert all the rows from the temp table into the perm table
-- if none of the rows in the temp table exist in the perm table

-- Insert none of the rows from the temp table into the perm table
-- if any of the rows in the temp table exist in the perm table

insert perm_table (key_field_a, key_field_b, attrib_c, attrib_d, attrib_e)
    select key_field_a, key_field_b, attrib_c, attrib_d, attrib_e from #temp_table
where not exists 
(
    select *
    from #temp_table temp
    join perm_table perm
        on perm.key_field_a = temp.key_field_a
        and perm.key_field_b = temp.key_field_b
)
```

Comment: Should I change the condition to
```where not exists 
(
 select key_field_a, key_field_b
 from #temp_table 
 intersect 
 select key_field_a, key_field_b
 from perm_table
)
```

Comment: The subquery should not be referencing the temporary table again; it should be a correlated subquery.

Comment: Though if you *know* none of the rows exist, then why a subquery at all?

Comment: Please see the comments in the code. None, some or all the rows in the temp table may or may not already be in the perm_table. If none exist (and I do not know that ahead of time) all the rows from the temp table need to go into the perm table. If even one row already exists, then none of them should go into the perm table. The queries above work - I am just looking for a more efficient way of doing this if possible.

Comment: The above checks to see if a no (matching) rows exists and then inserts them all. If only 1 out of 1,000s already existed in the table none would be inserted; is that your actual goal? If not, then the above query isn't "working" (as intended).

Comment: @Thom - I did say 'Insert none of the rows from the temp table, if any of the rows in the temp table exist in the perm table' and again 'If even one row already exists, then none of them should go into the perm table'. So the query is indeed working as intended - I just needed someone to help me make it better, which SelVazi did below.

Comment: What does "better" mean?

Comment: That solution from SelVazi *doesn't* do that then , @hsbatra , and therefore is *not* the solution you want. That will insert rows that don't exist, not none if theres at least one. What you have for you you describe (in the comments) seems like what you want.

Comment: @Thom - On further testing, agree that SelVazi's solution will insert any/all rows that do not YET exist in the perm table. Not the solution I was looking for. Going with my own "intersect" variation.

Answer (score 3):

You only want to allow the insert, if none of the rows is in the table yet. You identify the rows by the table's key consisting of key_field_a and key_field_b. With a properly set up database there is a unique constraint on these key columns, probably as the table's primary key.

You can hence reduce your insert statement to a mere

```
insert into perm_table (key_field_a, key_field_b, attrib_c, attrib_d, attrib_e)
  select key_field_a, key_field_b, attrib_c, attrib_d, attrib_e from #temp_table;
```

If any of the keys already exists in the table, you'll get a unique key constraint exception and none of the rows will be inserted.

Comment: Yes, that would work but then I would have to handle the unique key constraint exception. What you are suggesting is not wrong, it's just not what I was looking for. Going to upvote your answer anyway! Thank you!

Comment: @hsbatra I agree with Thorsten Kettner's answer - This is the best way to handle your specific requirement, even if it involves exception handling (which can be done on the tsql level)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this query :

```
with cte as (
  select temp.key_field_a, temp.key_field_b, temp.attrib_c, temp.attrib_d, temp.attrib_e,
  sum(case when perm.key_field_a is not null then 1 else 0 end) over() as existing_in_perm
  from #temp_table as temp
  left join perm_table perm
     on perm.key_field_a = temp.key_field_a
     and perm.key_field_b = temp.key_field_b
)
insert into perm_table
select key_field_a, key_field_b, attrib_c, attrib_d, attrib_e
from cte 
where existing_in_perm = 0;
```

`sum() over()` used here to check if any of the rows already exists, ( 0 if none exists )

Then the insert will be performed only if none of the records exists on `perm_table`

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/7-ketLqv)

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's specific problem. Note that if any of the rows already exists, none of them should be inserted.

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks for the remark,  I updated my answer, can you have look

Comment: IMHO This is an over complication and I'm not even sure it does what you think it does (don't have the time to test it myself).  I still think that Thorsten Kettner's answer is the best solution to this problem.